# SQL error in [stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]: started

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3, data-migration-tool, eav-attributes

I have this issue where I get the following error in the `[stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]`

> In Mysql.php line 110:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')) ORDER BY
>   `entity_attribute_id` ASC    LIMIT 216' at line 1, query was: SELECT
>   `eav_entity_attribute`.* FROM `eav_entity_attribute` WHERE
>   (`entity_attribute_id` >= 0) AND (attribute_id IN ()) ORDER BY
>   `entity_attribute_id` ASC    LIMIT 216

The issue is related to this part "attribute_id IN ()" because the selection is empty. However I do not know where this comes from.

In the map.xml I have both source and destination ignoring the eav document as such

```
<ignore>
   <document>eav_entity_attribute</document>
</ignore>
```

The migration tool is CE to CE from 1.9.4.5 to 2.3.5-p1. No other error appears prior to this step.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the same issue migrating a 1.9.2.4 store to 2.3.5-p1.

The issue appears to be in the tool at `src/Migration/Step/Eav/Data.php`
Around line 488. I got around it by checking if the attributes are set and not empty.

```
    /**
     * Migrate custom entity attributes
     */
    private function migrateCustomEntityAttributes()
    {
        $this->progress->advance();
        $sourceDocName = 'eav_entity_attribute';
        $destinationDocument = $this->destination->getDocument(
            $this->map->getDocumentMap($sourceDocName, MapInterface::TYPE_SOURCE)
        );
        $recordsToSave = $destinationDocument->getRecords();
        $customAttributeIds = $this->modelData->getCustomAttributeIds();
        //Added this line
        if(isset($customAttributeIds) && !empty($customAttributeIds)){
            $customEntityAttributes = $this->source->getRecords(
                $sourceDocName,
                0,
                $this->source->getRecordsCount($sourceDocName),
                new \Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('attribute_id IN (%s)', implode(',', $customAttributeIds)))
            );

        foreach ($customEntityAttributes as $record) {
            $record['sort_order'] = $this->getCustomAttributeSortOrder($record);
            $record['attribute_group_id'] = $this->mapAttributeGroupIdsSourceDest[$record['attribute_group_id']];
            $record['entity_attribute_id'] = null;
            $destinationRecord = $this->factory->create(['document' => $destinationDocument, 'data' => $record]);
            $recordsToSave->addRecord($destinationRecord);
            }
        //And this line
        }
        $this->saveRecords($destinationDocument, $recordsToSave);
    }
```